# Can I use "me" in this context?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

1. Is it correct to use me here?
2. I have read sentences should be no more than 25 words in practice.
   Would you say this one is too long?

"Never did I imagine that **me**, a small town girl from Alabama, would one day be helping to shape the minds of Aboriginals in Australia the intricacies of social norms in modern society."

Comment: For clarity, leave out the description between the commas.  "Never did I imagine that me would ..." vs. "Never did I imagine that I would..."

Comment: This may be a regionalism. Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English), and do a text search for "Alabama" (for relevance) and then "Me and him".

Answer (score 2):

You need to use *I*, not *me*, in your sentence. Sentence length depends more on clarity for the reader than number of words. However, there is a word missing, perhaps *on*, *concerning*, or *regarding*:

Never did I imagine that **I**, a small town girl from Alabama, would one day be helping to shape the minds of Aboriginals in Australia **regarding** the intricacies of social norms in modern society."

Answer (score 0):

I think more correct is the word "I"

> Never did I imagine that I, a small town girl from Alabama...

No to your second question, that does not seem unnaturally long for a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I should be used as the subject pronoun of the verb would.
Never did I imagine that I ... would one day be helping ...

The sentence isn't too long but it does lose clarity at the end. 'to shape the minds of Aboriginal in Australia the intricacies of social norms in modern society' doesn't make sense. What do you mean by this?